# Описать полиморфную связь Django

Tags: django, django-orm

Подскажите, как описать такую связь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется таблица в которой могут быть разные типы записей (Type1, Type2 или Type3).

Читал про [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations), видимо это то, что нужно, но похоже не совсем понял, как он работает. Как провести связь и выбрать потом, что я хочу в type записать, например Type2?

Соответственно, описал model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class General(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'General'

  class Type1(models.Model):
    name = GenericRelation(General)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Type1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type2 = Type2.objects.get(id=1) # получаем или создаём обьект type 
General.objects.create(content_object=type2) # передаём его при создании связанного обьекта
# или 
General.objects.create(ccontent_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Type2), object_id=1)

# для фильтрации принцип такой же
# модель ContentType хранит все созданные модели в проекте, что бы по id 
# нужной модели из ContentType и id обьекта из вашей модели осуществлять
# свзять с обьектами разных моделей
```